# Rigging. When i try to rotate bones, the shapes are distorted

Tags: rigging, pose-mode

I have rigged my character.  In the pose mode, when I try to rotate these bones, the shapes are distorted in weird ways.

This is the mesh:
[image]

How it is in weight mode:
[image]

This is how I posed it :
[image]

...And my regrettable result.
[image]

This is the type of result I am aiming at; very smooth folding of the arm.
[image]
Would there be any tips for rigging & posing this kind of round limbs?

Thanks!

Comment: if you're planning to use it only in Blender, you don't need it to be so high-poly, keep it low-poly and give it a Subdivision Surface modifier. Your weight painting is not good, the upper arm bone should influence the upper arm part of the mesh, not the middle. Also maybe try b-bones

Comment: if you haven't done this already try adding loop cuts in edit mode where you want the bending points of the mesh to be.  That should significantly clean up the mesh and make it more round like you want it

Comment: and don't worry about spamming questions.  It's always ok to ask questions.  Especially if you're just beginning blender. : )

Comment: Hi! Thanks for trying to help me. It seems like to me that adding loop cuts is just adding more vertices to my model and the results are pretty much the same.